# Why is Killer Bee still alive?

Tags: naruto

I just want to ask, in Naruto Shipuden when Madara extracted all the Tailed Beast by using the [Gedo Statue](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Demonic_Statue_of_the_Outer_Path). It is said that when the tailed beast is removed from a Jinjuriki the Jinjuriki will die.

I just want to ask, why was killer bee not dead and was able to have a dream under the infinite tsukoyumi. How is it possible?

Comment: Wasn't it just Naruto that got the Tailed Beast extracted during the war? IIRC Madara didn't need Gyuuki/Hachibi since he already have a part of Gyuuki (a tentacle Sasuke retrieved) sealed inside the Gedo Mazo.

Comment: Isn't it that Madara Also have the chakra of the Nine Tails ?? anyways ,Ahmm, i saw it that the Gedo released the color violet chakra chains that got the neck of the of all the tailed beast that includes Gyuuki.

Answer (score 10):

According to this [link](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Gy%C5%ABki)

> Madara then proceeded to chain them up and prepared to remove
>   Yang-Kurama and Gyūki from their jinchūriki. Struggling against its
>   confines, Gyūki apologised to B as it was extracted and sealed within
>    the statue along with the other tailed beasts, 
>   **but not before cutting
>    off one of its tentacles, letting B survive through the chakra within
>    it.**

So in short he was having chakra worth of one tentacle which was cut off from Gyūki and just because of this he was able to survive.

[image]

Comment: Kurama should have done this too.

Answer (score 0):

> Bee used a tentacle escape pod. It's using the same rule that allowed
>   the Jubi to be revived in reverse. As long as there was a portion of
>   Gyuki's chakra, be was able to survive.

as stated [here](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:137687)

Comment: are you sure about this ?

Comment: His answer is right, but it's generally not good to just quote forum comments, since they cannot be considered credible.

Answer (score 0):

So yall know how naruto survives from getting the yang 9 tails removed, well its kinda the same thing that happened only he only had a little of the tailed beast's chakra inside him. B had one tentacles worth of chakra remain inside of him.